# OSGI: how to export system packages on felix during runtime

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

When I need to export some system packages I do:

```
final Map configMap = new HashMap();
configMap.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, "onFirstInit");
configMap.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,"my packageshere");
felix = new Felix(configMap);
```

But how can I export some packages during runtime? For example, on working osgi framework I want to install some bundle which requires some system packages which I didn't export when I start felix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this dynamically. And I am not sure I understand the purpose since the packages are known ahead of time when you start the framework. Why not export all?

Comment: Suppose you have application which can download extension to itself. The extension has N bundles. Some bundles need some extra system packages. Will you restart every time you application? Another example - you use web container on osgi and deploy your web application. If new web app requires some system packages - will you stop all other web app?

Comment: No, I would just export ALL packages since this is by definition a finite set. (Unless you do some class loading hacks on the framework side of your code?)

Comment: I understand what you say, maybe this is the only solution. However, it is strange because if bundles are so dynamic then and the environment for them must have dynamic properties.

Comment: @JimJim2000 The environment has the capability to support dynamic properties; it cannot be dynamic "all the way down". By analogy: you can build a dynamic structure like a ferris wheel or a swing bridge, but it still has a solid, immovable foundation.

Comment: The system has dynamic properties, you can install a new bundle that can provide new packages to the environment _inside_ the framework. This is a (very complex) function of the framework. If you could provide this kind of functionality outside the framework, why would you then need an OSGi framework?